# how to approximate time-series data

Tags: charts, time-series, smoothing, approximation

I'm not sure if this is the right term but I think I want to s̶m̶o̶o̶t̶h̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶/̶o̶r̶ approximate a data set. I have 30 data points as it is presented in the chart below (the red line with dots)
I want to approximate the dataset so it can be described with fewer data points. The black line represents what I want to achieve.[image: chart1]

I want to be able to define an approximation level which will control how much the result data set will differ from the original one.
The approximated data set should contain a set of data points which I can connect together using straight lines.

What is the right algorithm or a math function to solve this problem? I don't expect an implementation here, but rather some suggestions where to start.

I wrote my implementation of the approximation algorithm. It works in most of the cases, but there are certain situations in which it returns non-optimal data.
The example below shows three dotted lines. Thin red line is the original dataset, a thick red-black dotted line is generated by my algorithm, the green line is what I'd like to achieve.

[image: my implementation]

```
        var previousValue;
        return array.map(function (dataPoint, index, fullArray) {
            var approximation = dataPoint;

            if (index > 0) {
                if (Math.abs(previousValue - value) < tolerance) {
                    approximation = previousValue;
                } else {
                    previousValue = dataPoint;
                }

            } else {
                previousValue = dataPoint;
            }

            return approximation;
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? I doubt there is a standard algorithm that fits your black line as your x axis points are not evenly spaced. Consider using a "moving average" to smooth the data and then pick every n points to reduce the number of points.

Comment: to simplify thing, let's assume that the points on the x-axis are aligned to the red dots but there is fewer of them. 
I wrote my own algorithm to do the approximation which basically goes from left to right and ignores all the points which are within a certain tolerance level. If some value exceeds the tolerance level, a new data point is created and set as a new comparison base. The algo works ok, but there are cases in which it's not perfect. This is why I'm asking if there is any generic solution so I don't have to re-invent the wheel. I've added example outputs of my algo above.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here:

1. if the shown "glitch" in the data is significant, meaning that you cannot smooth it.
2. if all data shown can be approximated and the "glitch" is insignificant

In (1) case, you may consider approximate by templates (e.g. wavelet) or use basic differential analysis to detect and keep the "glitch" (e.g. meshes).
In (2) case, you may use MA, ARIMA to fit, where the "glitch" can be analyzed further through the roots

Answer (score 1):

Okay, point of clarification, are you looking to smooth the data or approximate it? If you are going to smooth the data, by definition, it will get rid of the little bumps and dips in the data series. On the other hand if the goal is to accurately portray all those dips and bumps, then you do NOT want smoothing. I'm going to talk about smoothing, you tell me if you want the other.

Okay, the best way I know to smooth data is to use an alpha value. The equation is T<sub>n+1</sub>=(1-α)T<sub>n</sub>+αData<sub>n+1</sub>. What this means is that you set the portion of the next function point which is affected by your series history and the portion which is affected by the current data point.

[Example graph with alpha = .5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DckS4.png)
Take a look at this data. Here the α=.5. So the function conforms to the data, but not a lot. The one below is the same, but the alpha is .25. So the data is followed even less, but the function is a lot smoother. There is also a third option where α decreases over time. Initially it can be very high, so you quickly follow the data, but then as α decreases over time the trend becomes smoother and stays smooth over time. Finally, you can set a hard limit on the minimum α This will ensure that you will always have some minimum responsiveness to the data.

[Example graph with alpha = .25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5nfc.png)

Comment: ok, thank you for your explanation. It helped me to understand that what I really need is an approximation. Essentially, I want to reduce the number of data points and stay as close as possible to the original shape of the graph. My first chart shows the approximation of the red data set as a black line. I need only 5 points to describe that line (including the start and the end points)